# PostgreSQL Aggregates with Multiple Parameters

Tags: postgresql, aggregates

I've been trying to wrap my head around creating aggregates in PostgreSQL (either 8.4 or 9.1) that accept one or more option parameters.

An example would be creating a `PL/R` extension to compute the p-th quantile, with `0 <= p <= 1`. This would look something like `quantile(x,p)`, and as part of a query:

```
select category,quantile(x,0.25)
from TABLE
group by category
order by category;
```

Where `TABLE (category:text, x:float)`.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Hopefully this example will help. You need a function that takes (accumulator, aggregate-arguments) and returns the new accumulator value. Play around with the code below and that should give you a feel for how it all fits together.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE FUNCTION sum_product_fn(int,int,int) RETURNS int AS $$
    SELECT $1 + ($2 * $3);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;           

CREATE AGGREGATE sum_product(int, int) (
    sfunc = sum_product_fn,
    stype = int, 
    initcond = 0
);

SELECT 
    sum(i) AS one,     
    sum_product(i, 2) AS double,
    sum_product(i,3) AS triple
FROM generate_series(1,3) i;

ROLLBACK;
```

That should give you something like:

```
 one | double | triple 
-----+--------+--------
   6 |     12 |     18
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with the ntile windowing function

```
-- To calculate flexible quantile ranges in postgresql, for example to calculate n equal 
-- frequency buckets for your data for use in a visualisation (such as binning for a 
-- choropleth map), you can use the following SQL:

-- this functions returns 6 equal frequency bucket ranges for my_column.
SELECT ntile, avg(my_column) AS avgAmount, max(my_column) AS maxAmount, min(my_column) AS     minAmount 
FROM (SELECT my_column, ntile(6) OVER (ORDER BY my_column) AS ntile FROM my_table) x
GROUP BY ntile ORDER BY ntile
```

You can find more on the ntile() function and windowing at http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2010/11/really-cool-ntile-window-function.html

Comment: Downvote because, while this is definitely useful for calculating quartile ranges, the question pertains to creating aggregate functions.